# Removing picture from a movieclip AS 3.0

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, mask, movieclip

I made a portfolio flash using the code below.
It works fine but I have a problem.
Since the pictures have different sizes, when a smaller picture is loaded the previous image is still in the background.
Can you help me telling how I can show only the current picture clearing the background.

Thanks in advance

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
var loader:Loader;
var loading:TextField = new TextField();
var image:Bitmap;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var files:Array= new Array();
var titles:Array= new Array();
var description:Array= new Array();
var index:int = 0;
var pictures:int = 0;

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("images.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, readXML);

function readXML(e:Event):void {

XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
var images:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
pictures = images.picture.length();
for (var i:Number=0; i<pictures; i++) {
    titles[i]=images.picture[i].title.text();
    files[i]=images.picture[i].file.text();
    description[i]=images.picture[i].description.text();
}
load(0);
}

function load(index:int):void {

circle.visible = false;

loader=new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(files[index]));

text_folio.text = titles[index];
description_folio.text = description[index];

//loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("progress",progressLoad);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("complete",completeLoad);
}

function progressLoad(e:Event):void {
loading.x=100;
loading.y=100;
stage.addChild(loading);
loading.text="Loading: ";

var tFormat:TextFormat=new TextFormat();
tFormat.size = 20;
tFormat.color = 0x888888;
loading.setTextFormat(tFormat);
}

function completeLoad(e:Event):void {
bigImg.mask = null;
image=Bitmap(loader.content);
bigImg.addChild(image);

//create the small image from the big image
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bigImg.width, bigImg.height);
bmp.draw(bigImg);

var bitmap2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
bitmap2.scaleX /=2;
bitmap2.scaleY /=2;
smallImg.addChild(bitmap2);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener("progress",progressLoad);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener("complete",completeLoad);

loader=null;

loading.text="";
loading.visible=false;

circle.visible = true;
bigImg.mask = circle;//add the circle mask to the big image
stage.addEventListener("enterFrame",mGlass);

}

function mGlass(e:Event) {
bigImg.x = (mouseX * -1);
bigImg.y = (mouseY * -1);

circle.x = (mouseX-150);
circle.y = (mouseY-150);
}

left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonLeft);
right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonRight);

function buttonRight(event:MouseEvent):void {
if (index == pictures-1)
    index = 0;
else
    index++;
load(index);
}

function buttonLeft(event:MouseEvent):void {
if (index == 0)
    index = pictures-1;
else
    index--;
load(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mock up of your setup and this is what I've come up with.

This code will have a look inside bigImg and see how many display children it has in it and then loops through all of them and deletes them. (This method makes the presumption that there is nothing else inside the bigImg Movieclip). Do ask if you aren't entirely sure how it works, but it should be reasonably self explanatory.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < bigImg.numChildren; i++) {
    bigImg.removeChildAt(i);
}
```

This should be added into the `load` function before making the `loader.load` call.

```
function load(index:int):void {
    var i:int;
    for (i = 0; i < bigImg.numChildren; i++) {
        bigImg.removeChildAt(i);
    }
    circle.visible = false;
    loader=new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest(files[index]));
    text_folio.text = titles[index];
    description_folio.text = description[index];    
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("progress",progressLoad);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("complete",completeLoad);
}
```